# how to iterate dic when i have one value and many values in another key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need to iterate below dict and add the values in a variable and when i check the dic 1:2:140 i get below error because is not iterable

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

what solution do i have here?

```
dm = {1: {1: {80, 75, 46, 2: 140}, 2: {1: 400}}

def listGastos(dm):
    for mes in dm:
        totalmes = 0
        maxconsumomes = 0
        diamax = 0
        print("MES: ", mes)
        for dia in dm[mes]:
            print("DIA:", dia)
            for va in dm[mes][dia]:
                print("El amount is", va)
                totalmes + = va
```

Comment: The definition of the dictionary `d` is incorrect. Can you please correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary definition seems incorrect.

dm = {1: {1: {80, 75, 46, 2: 140}, 2: {1: 400}}

EOF is incorrect ...You need to add another '}' at the end.

Also, you've inserted a key,value pair '2:140' which will generate Syntax error but you can fix it by doing this :

dm = {1: {1: [80, 75, 46, {2: 140}], 2: {1: 400}}}

Now, the solution to your query goes like this :

```py
dm = {1: {1: [80, 75, 46, {2: 140}], 2: {1: 400}}}

tot = 0
for key,val in dm.items() :
    if isinstance(val,dict) :
        for nex_t in val.values() :
            if isinstance(nex_t,list) :
                for i in nex_t :
                    if isinstance(i,dict) :
                        loc_tot = 0
                        i = list(i.values())
                        nex_t.append(*i)
                        nex_t.pop(-2)
                        loc_tot = sum(nex_t)
            if isinstance(nex_t,dict) :
                tot = sum(nex_t.values()) + loc_tot                    
print(tot)
```

And the output will be 741.